# GCMINTENTSERVICE onRegistered called but onMessage is not

Tags: android

Hello people (please excuse my english because i speak spanish). I'm new on android and i'm working in a project using google cloud messaging.

But we are having a problem, in the class GCMINTENTSERVICE the method onMessage is never called, we try with differents solutions that was found here, but no luck. On think we note while debbuging is tha the method onRegistered is called ok and returns and google ID.

Here is my code
Package name = com.snappy

```
public class GCMReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        return "com.snappy.GCMIntentService";
    }
```

GCMINTENTSERVICE

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static int mNotificationCounter = 1;
    public final static String PUSH = "com.snappy.GCMIntentService.PUSH";
    private static final Intent mPushBroadcast = new Intent(PUSH);

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(Const.PUSH_SENDER_ID);
    }

    private final String TAG = "=== GCMIntentService ===";

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        if (!registrationId.equals(null)) {
            savePushTokenAsync(registrationId, Const.ONLINE, context);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device unregistered
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

        if (!registrationId.equals(null)) {
            removePushTokenAsync(context);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle pushExtras = intent.getExtras();
        String pushMessage = intent.getStringExtra(Const.PUSH_MESSAGE);
        String pushFromName = intent.getStringExtra(Const.PUSH_FROM_NAME);
        try {
            boolean appIsInForeground = new SpikaApp.ForegroundCheckAsync()
                    .execute(getApplicationContext()).get();

            boolean screenLocked = ((KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE))
                    .inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();


            if (appIsInForeground && !screenLocked) {
                mPushBroadcast.replaceExtras(pushExtras);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(mPushBroadcast);
                generateNotification(this, pushMessage, pushFromName, pushExtras);
            } else {
                triggerNotification(this, pushMessage, pushFromName, pushExtras);
                generateNotification(this, pushMessage, pushFromName, pushExtras);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
        Logger.error(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void triggerNotification(Context context, String message,
            String fromName, Bundle pushExtras) {

        if (fromName != null) {
            final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification notification = new Notification(
                    R.drawable.icon_notification, message,
                    System.currentTimeMillis());

            notification.number = mNotificationCounter + 1;
            mNotificationCounter = mNotificationCounter + 1;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
            intent.replaceExtras(pushExtras);
            intent.putExtra(Const.PUSH_INTENT, true);
            intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    notification.number, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name), message,
                    pendingIntent);

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            String notificationId = Double.toString(Math.random());
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, 0, notification);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message,
            String fromName, Bundle pushExtras) {

        // Open a new activity called GCMMessageView
                Intent intento = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
                intento.replaceExtras(pushExtras);
                // Pass data to the new activity
                intento.putExtra(Const.PUSH_INTENT, true);

                // Starts the activity on notification click
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intento,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                // Create the notification with a notification builder
                        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
                                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                .setContentTitle("Android GCM Tutorial")
                                .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                                .getNotification();

                // Remove the notification on click
                        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        manager.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);
                        {
                            // Wake Android Device when notification received
                            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                            final PowerManager.WakeLock mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(
                                    PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "GCM_PUSH");
                            mWakelock.acquire();
                            // Timer before putting Android Device to sleep mode.
                            Timer timer = new Timer();
                            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                                public void run() {
                                    mWakelock.release();
                                }
                            };
                            timer.schedule(task, 5000);
                        }
    }

    private void savePushTokenAsync (String pushToken, String onlineStatus, Context context) {
        new SpikaAsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(new SavePushToken(pushToken, onlineStatus), new SavePushTokenListener(pushToken), context, false).execute();
    }

    private class SavePushToken implements Command<Boolean>{

        String pushToken;
        String onlineStatus;

        public SavePushToken (String pushToken, String onlineStatus) {
            this.pushToken = pushToken;
            this.onlineStatus = onlineStatus;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean execute() throws JSONException, IOException,
                SpikaException, IllegalStateException, SpikaForbiddenException {

            /* set new androidToken and onlineStatus */
            UsersManagement.getLoginUser().setOnlineStatus(onlineStatus);
            SpikaApp.getPreferences().setUserEmail(UsersManagement.getLoginUser().getEmail());
            SpikaApp.getPreferences().setUserPushToken(pushToken);
            return CouchDB.updateUser(UsersManagement.getLoginUser());
        }
    }

    private class SavePushTokenListener implements ResultListener<Boolean>{

        String currentPushToken;

        public SavePushTokenListener (String currentPushToken) {
            this.currentPushToken = currentPushToken;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResultsSucceded(Boolean result) {
            if (result) {
            } else {
                SpikaApp.getPreferences().setUserPushToken(currentPushToken);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResultsFail() {
        }

    }

    private void removePushTokenAsync (Context context) {
        SpikaApp.getPreferences().setUserPushToken("");
        if (UsersManagement.getLoginUser() != null) {
            CouchDB.unregisterPushTokenAsync(UsersManagement.getLoginUser().getId(), new RemovePushTokenListener(), context, false);
        }
    }

    private class RemovePushTokenListener implements ResultListener<String> {
        @Override
        public void onResultsSucceded(String result) {
            if (result != null && result.contains("OK")) {
                SpikaApp.getPreferences().setUserEmail("");
                SpikaApp.getPreferences().setUserPassword("");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onResultsFail() {
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.snappy"
    android:versionCode="14"
    android:versionName="1.31" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />



    <permission
        android:name="com.snappy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.snappy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.snappy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.snappy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name=".SpikaApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBH1T5IsUDDeA0EDwRByyK58D9xn3OjcGs" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="user"
                    android:scheme="spikademo" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="group"
                    android:scheme="spikademo" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.SignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.WallActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.extendables.SideBarActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.extendables.HookUpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.extendables.HookUpFragmentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.PasscodeActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.UsersActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.GroupsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.PhotoActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.CreateGroupActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.CameraCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.MyProfileActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.UserProfileActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.GroupProfileActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.MembersActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.LocationActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.RecordingActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.VoiceActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.InformationActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.SettingsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.RecordingVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.RecentActivityActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.dialog.Tutorial"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/TransparentDialogTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.snappy.ServersListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.snappy" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.snappy.management.ConnectionChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.snappy.management.LogoutReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".management.LogoutReceiver.LOGOUT" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Google register method in activity

```
private String registerOnGCM() {

        if (Const.PUSH_SENDER_ID == null || Const.PUSH_SENDER_ID.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.recentactivity_nosender_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getApplicationContext());
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getApplicationContext());

         if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this))
         {
             Log.d("Info Registration ID", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
         }

        String registrationId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
        System.out.println("registration ID is " + registrationId);
       // GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), Const.PUSH_SENDER_ID);

        if (registrationId.equals("") || registrationId.equals(null)) {
            System.out.println("Ingresando a registrar ID " + registrationId);
            GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), Const.PUSH_SENDER_ID);
            Log.d("Luego de tratar de registrar", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
            System.out.println("Get Reg ID: " + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));

        } else {
            // // Device is already registered on GCM
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(getApplicationContext())) {
                Log.d("info", "already registered as" + registrationId);
            } else {

            }
        }
        return GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

Please help!
Best regards

Comment: Have you Receiving a message via push notification?

Comment: Yes im trying to receive it via push notifications. But without luck until now. My server appear to work ok

Comment: I mean to say have got you got any notification till now or not because onMessage() method is called when you receive the notification if you are not getting notification your onMessage() method will not get call

Comment: Until now i didn`t receive any notification.The only code i have in my app is the one here

Comment: Go through this link.This may help you
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/